# Homomorphism with element of given order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm slightly confused as to how to use order of elements in proving homomorphism.

Let g be an element of order 4 in a group G.

$\varphi (k)=g^k$

Does the formula define a homomorphism when:

**1)** $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow G$

**2)** $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}_4 \rightarrow G$

My attempt looks something like this:

$\varphi(a+b)=g^{a+b}=g^ag^b=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$

I tried proving by contradiction using G = $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and the element $g = 1$ which has order $4$. Now,

$\varphi(k)=1^k$

$\varphi(a+b)=1^{a+b}=1^a1^b=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$

This looks like it's mapping everything to 1, but I expected the answer to be no, that it is not a homomorphism, since $gcd(2,4)=2$ it's only two homomorphisms and this is not one of them. Where did I mess up? I should perhaps have chosen an element like $g=(1234) \in S_4 = G$...

**Edit:**

If I set

$\varphi(1+1) = \varphi(0) = 1^0 = 0$

$\varphi(1) + \varphi(1) = 1^1 + 1^1 = 2$

Is this a valid counterexample since $0 \ne 2$?

Appreciate any help in clearing this out.

Comment: A couple of things. One, in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$, the operation is addition, so $1^{k}$ means 1 added to itself $k$ times - i.e. $k$ mod 4.

Your edit is almost right. $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}_{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{4}$ will not be a homomorphism, but again, $\varphi(1+1) = \varphi(0) = 1^{0} = 0$. That $1^{0}$ again needs to be translated into addition.

In general, this problem is not about checking the homomorphism property $\varphi(ab) = \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$. It's about whether $\varphi$ is well-defined on its domain.

Comment: Side note: "Proof by contradiction" is not the right phrase for what you're doing. You're finding a counterexample for part 1.

Comment: @coolpapa Ah yes of course, the notation is so confusing but of course it's addition and not multiplication. I think I should start writing $+_2$ and $+_4$ and stuff such as, so I wont confuse myself even more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g\in G$, there is a unique homomorphism $\psi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G$ such that $\psi(1)=g$, precisely
$$
\psi(k)=g^k.
$$
The operation on $\mathbb{Z}$ is addition and I'm using multiplicative notation on $G$.

The image of $\psi$ is exactly $\langle g\rangle=\{g^k:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$; so, if $g$ has (finite) order $n$, the kernel of $\psi$ must be $n\mathbb{Z}$, because by the homomorphism theorem there is a homomorphism $\bar{\psi}\colon\mathbb{Z}/\ker\psi\to G$ such that $\psi=\bar\psi\circ\pi$, where $\pi\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/ker\psi$ is the canonical projection. It's immediate that $\psi$ and $\bar\psi$ have the same image, so
$$
|\mathbb{Z}/\ker\psi|=n=|\langle g\rangle|
$$
forcing $\ker\psi=n\mathbb{Z}$.

Your homomorphism $\varphi$ is just my $\bar\psi$.

Comment: Thus, since $n=|\langle g\rangle|$ 1) Not homomorphism 2) Homomorphism. Right?

Comment: @ExceptionalException Yes.